# Video Quality Loss after Rendering in VSE

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, video

I rendered an animation in a 720p-png format and the images looked HQ. After re-rendering them into video in VSE the video lost its quality and looked blurred. (I tried higher bitrates and different formats but nothing worked). How to keep my video quality as good as images?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40569/what-settings-will-preserve-quality-when-i-output-an-edited-mp4-for-youtube-upl/41005#41005

Comment: Have you tried using H.264 and the H.264 preset? I had similar issues and this worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Rendering with the file format **AVI Raw** should help you retain your Quality ;-)

But if you don't want to have your file sizes explode try **H.264** instead.

[image: Example of Output and Encoding settings]

You can reduce your Bitrate to [5000](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1722171?hl=en) for your 720p video. Change your GOP Size to half your Frame Rate.