# Best lossless video output format for later conversions for web

Tags: cycles-render-engine, export, video, file-format, audio

I'm creating an animation (with sound) in blender that's gonna be an HTML5 video. As [browsers are quite picky](http://blog.zencoder.com/2013/09/13/what-formats-do-i-need-for-html5-video/), I'll probably need to embed the video into the web page in multiple different formats for an universal support. - [A single MPEG-4/H.264 might be enough](http://caniuse.com/#search=mp4), however, there isn't seem to be a way to tell blender to keep it in baseline. So anyhow I try, I just cannot produce one video file using blender that would go well in all browsers.

---

Therefore my idea is to create the animation in some lossless format first, and then convert it to the formats I need for the `<video>` tag (I guess these are MP4/H.264 with baseline profile and WebM.) using some video editor. So I'm looking for a file format+coding combo which is

1. supported by blender to export to,
2. lossless, (or near lossless if there isn't a completely lossless option)
3. and not too hard to be converted into the final formats I'll need.

*Ps: I've found [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7051/lossless-compression-for-video-with-audio) thread previously. Should I also go with H264 lossless, or are there better options in my case? Or... do I even need an external tool, or can I maybe export proper HTML5 videos directly to web from blender? This would be the best.*